# What do I use as the argument for the `click()` method when the button has no name or ID?

Tags: java, selenium-rc, element

I'm using the Java Selenium RC and I want to know how to use the click method from the DefaultSelenium. How do I specify to click a button? I know when I use the "Inspect Element" on a button sometimes it says `name=btng` or `id="search"` but sometimes it has neither. When this is the case, what do I use as the argument for the `click()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium supports a number of strategies for locating an element on a page, including id, name, css, xpath, etc.  Details on the supported Element Locators can be found [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#locators).